# Datetime picker below div

Tags: jquery, datetime, z-index

Can anyone help me discover why my datetime picker is hiding behind the rest of the divs?

http://www.lcslegal.co.uk/booking-form.html

I have added this line of css to try and fix it in custom.css but to no avail:

```
.ui-datepicker, #ui-timepicker-div { z-index:1003; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class `col1` has a `z-index` of 10.  If I manually change the the datepicker to have `z-index` of 1003, it seems to work.  Why don't you try using the CSS on the named DIVs instead of the classes.

```
#ui-datepicker-div, #ui-timepicker-div { z-index: 1003; }
```

Comment: Still didnt work for a while very strangely but its working now adding

#ui-timepicker-div { z-index:1000; }

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If the `input` has a `position: absolute;` (or `relative` or `fixed`)
then the `z-index` of the `input` is taken to set the `z-index` of the datepicker (+1)

e.g.

```
input.setAttribute( "style", "position: relative; z-index: 1000" );
$(input).datepicker( .....
```

results in a datepicker with `z-index`: 1001

Answer (score 0):

It work when I add `z-index: 1000` to "custom.css" with **Firebug**...

custom.css (line 293)

```
.ui-datepicker {
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em 0;
  width: 17em;
  z-index: 1000; /* added */
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

i tried to set z-index: 1000; and it worked

[image: Booking Form]